# Hive error on CREATE

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I'm following [these instructions](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example) and I've got to running Hive. I ran the following commands:

```
ADD JAR /home/cloudera/Downloads/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
  id BIGINT,
  created_at STRING,
  source STRING,
  favorited BOOLEAN,
   retweeted_status STRUCT<
    text:STRING,
    user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,
    retweet_count:INT>,
  entities STRUCT<
    urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
    user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
    hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
  text STRING,
  user STRUCT<
    screen_name:STRING,
    name:STRING,
    friends_count:INT,
    followers_count:INT,
    statuses_count:INT,
    verified:BOOLEAN,
    utc_offset:INT,
    time_zone:STRING>,
  in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
) 
PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/home/cloudera/flume/tweets';
```

and then I encountered an error:

> CREATE does not exist
>   Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: CREATE does not exist.

As I'm new to Hive, I might be missing something obvious.
What might be causing such an error?

Comment: Could it be as simple as a missing semicolon after the add jar statement?

Comment: Will check, but it appears to be the only line that works.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be it: I added it and am now having permissions errors, which is arguably better.

Comment: Joe K: Add your comment as an answer so we can upvote it and it will be visible in future searches?

Comment: Yes, it was just a missing semicolon after all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error on my Hive console while runing hive commands:

create does not exist
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: create does not exist

I resolved this problem by setting the Hive run as user setting.

I changed it from "Run as end user instead of Hive user" from True to False and restarted Hive server/clients.

with this setting my hive commands started running with hive user and started working.

before making this setting the default user id the root user where hive was running from.

Answer (score 0):

This is hive setting issue please restart your hive console and check your hive-jdbc version and hadoop version compatability. Hope this will solve your issue as i can see the query is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't put `;` in the end of the first statement.

You need to change this:

```
ADD JAR /home/cloudera/Downloads/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Into this:

```
ADD JAR /home/cloudera/Downloads/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```